# Apache Camel http to http routing with transformation of response

Tags: java, http, routes, apache-camel

this is a kind of a follow-up question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646557/apache-camel-http-to-http-routing-is-it-possible).

So it is possible to do the http-http routing as described in the above url. Is it also possible to adjust the output, so that only a specific part is returned? E.g. the `<title>` of the Google-Page if we stick to the mentioned example..or enhance the output with additional info?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the route and do your transformation, to eg only contain the title of the google page.

pseudo route:

from jetty

to http

to processor

eg just add for example a processor, and in the processor you can change the message body/headers to contain what you want.