# Multicast in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am developing a web application with key distribution in jsp. The server updates the session key when a new client comes and must multicast the key to all clients. I cannot do this with servlet/jsp and using multicast socket in servlet is also not helpful. Please suggest me an approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer Camel framework.You can refer these links.they talk about multicasting.

[Apache Camel http to http routing (Is it possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646557/apache-camel-http-to-http-routing-is-it-possible)

[How to route from Camel servlet component to http component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825623/how-to-route-from-camel-servlet-component-to-http-component)

Hope this will help you.